# Difference between defined and undefined values of recursive functions

Tags: recursion, undefined, defined

I am trying to understand the difference between defined and undefined values of recursive functions. Is it similar to programming a loop in an imperative language, like Java, but there is an unseen mistake in the loop structure which causes variables to not contain the values that you were expecting them to contain?

Comment: I don't understand this question; what context are you seeing these terms used in?

Comment: Could you please add some context where these defined and undefined values are mentioned? I did not see these terms occur once when reading about recursive functions.

Comment: Are you referring to bound versus free variables? You can have both but in both cases they all have to be defined.